# Помогите исправить ошибки [1]

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, грамотная-речь

Я из Польши и должна написать эссе о традициях в моей стране. Вы можете посмотреть и сказать, какие в тексте ошибки, пожалуйста?
Я буду очень благодарна! :)

А здесь текст:

> Рождество в Польше
>
> Рождество это особа важный момент для всех последователей Христа в
>   течение года. Праздничное время сочетает в себе не только духовный
>   опыт, но и уникальный момент, проведенный в компании близких. Каждая
>   страна имеет свои традиции и обычаи, связанные с этим праздником.
>   Польша является страной богатой различными интересными традициями, а
>   Рождество это особый момент, указывая дружественного, веселого и
>   щедрого духа, который распространяется по всей стране.
>
> В Польше время празднования падает в декабре. Итак, когда первая
>   звезда, как символ начала праздничных чудес появляется на тёмном небе
>   24 дня декабря, поляки в компании близких сядут к Сочельнику. Однако,
>   прежде этого они поздравляют друг друга, а некоторые даже читают
>   фрагмент Священного Писания, связанного с рождением Иисуса Христа.
>   Многолетняя традиция диктует, чтобы на праздничном столе было
>   двенадцать блюд. Когда Польская хозяйка накрывая на стол, обязательно
>   кладет под скатерть немного сена, что знаменует место рождения Христа.
>
> На столе конечно не может пропустить основного кушанья, как борщ с
>   пельменями, карп и лапша с маком, изюмом и орехами. Традиция гласит,
>   что чем большое количество мака, тем больше счастья и удачи принесёт
>   наступающий год. После торжественного ужина  участники сидят вокруг
>   украшенной ёлки и вместе поют рождественские песни, ожидая Звездного
>   человека, который приносит ребёнком, и даже иногда взрослым, подарки.
>
> Поляки верят, что как проведешь Сочельник, так и будешь жить весь год
>   и потому что они стараются проводить этот день радостно и бес споров.
>   Праздник Рождества в Польше является символом счастья и благополучия,
>   а также времой распространения этой радости во всех уголках мира.

Comment: уровень у вас очень хороший для иностранца, но ошибок слишком много, чтобы их просто указывать. Грамматика и стиль выдают. Надо переписывать весь текст, а это уже плохая услуга.

Comment: Pani Marta, Co jest potrawa z makiem, rodzynkami i оrzechami? Makaron? Albo pączki, ciasto?

Comment: ААА! **kluski?** Клёцки. Или кнели. )))

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Исправленный текст, близкий по содержанию к оригиналу

**Рождество в Польше**

Рождество ―  очень важный момент для всех христиан. Это не только особый духовный опыт, но и время, проведенное в кругу  близких людей.  Каждая страна имеет свои обычаи, связанные с этим праздником. Польша богата  различными интересными традициями, и Рождество  для поляков ― это момент  повсеместного торжества дружественного, веселого и щедрого рождественского духа,

В Польше время празднования приходится на  декабрь. Итак, когда первая звезда, как символ начала праздничных чудес, появляется на тёмном небе,  24 дня декабря, поляки в компании близких садятся к Сочельнику. Но прежде этого они поздравляют друг друга, а иногда даже читают фрагмент Священного Писания, связанный с рождением Иисуса Христа. Многолетняя традиция обязывает, чтобы на праздничном столе было двенадцать блюд. Польская хозяйка,  накрывая на стол, обязательно кладет под скатерть немного сена, что знаменует место рождения Христа.

Конечно,  нельзя обойтись  без таких  традиционных кушаний, как борщ с пельменями, карп и лапша с маком, изюмом и орехами. Считается, что чем больше мака, тем больше счастья и удачи принесёт наступающий год. После торжественного ужина участники садятся вокруг украшенной ёлки и вместе поют рождественские песни, ожидая Звездного человека, который приносит подарки детям и взрослым.

Поляки верят, что как проведешь Сочельник, так и будешь жить весь год,  и потому они стараются провести этот день  в согласии и радости. Праздник Рождества в Польше является символом счастья и благополучия  во всех уголках мира.

Comment: фрагмент Священного Писания, связанного(?!) с рождением Иисуса Христа. Логичнее: "фрагмент, связанный"

Comment: Да, спасибо, текст исправлен.

Answer (score 0):

```
Рождество в Польше
```

> Рождество это особа важный момент для всех последователей Христа в течение года.

Тяжелый стиль - и плохо понятный. "Последователи Христа" - в русском языке это немножко не тот смысл, не католический, скорее уж баптистский (сектантство). Но трудно заменить на что-то не потеряв авторский смысл. Остальное переделать.

*Рождество - особ**о** важное ежегодное событие для всех последователей Христа.*

> Праздничное время сочетает в себе не только духовный опыт, но и
>   уникальный момент, проведенный в компании близких.

Опять стиль тяжелый и плохо понятный.
*Праздничное время посвящается не только духовному совершенствованию, но и встрече в семейном кругу  *

> Каждая страна имеет свои традиции и обычаи, связанные с этим
>   праздником.
>   +
>
> Польша является страной богатой различными интересными традициями, а
>   Рождество это особый момент, указывая дружественного, веселого и
>   щедрого духа, который распространяется по всей стране.

Польша является страной**,** богатой различными интересными традициями, 
Рождество это особое событие, проявление дружественного, веселого и
щедрого духа всей страны.

> В Польше время празднования падает в декабре.

Это не по-русски.
*В Польше Рождество празднуется в декабре*

> Итак, когда первая звезда, как символ начала праздничных чудес
>   появляется на тёмном небе 24 дня декабря, поляки в компании близких
>   сядут к Сочельнику.

*Когда 24-го декабря первая звезда - символ начала праздничных чудес - 
появляется на тёмном небе, поляки в компании близких
собираются к Сочельнику.*

> Однако, прежде этого они поздравляют друг друга, а некоторые даже
>   читают фрагмент Священного Писания, связанного с рождением Иисуса
>   Христа.

Но еще до этого они поздравляют друг друга, а некоторые даже
читают Священное Писание, фрагмент повествующий о рождении Иисуса
Христа.

> Многолетняя традиция диктует, чтобы на праздничном столе было
>   двенадцать блюд.

+

> Когда Польская хозяйка накрывая на стол, обязательно кладет под
>   скатерть немного сена, что знаменует место рождения Христа.

Здесь грамматика очень плохая, нет подлежащего и сказуемого.

*Когда Польская хозяйка **накрывает** на стол, **она** обязательно кладет под скатерть немного сена, что знаменует место рождения Христа.*

> На столе конечно не может пропустить основного кушанья, как борщ с
>   пельменями, карп и клёцки с маком, изюмом и орехами.

Тоже грамматика. И смысл.

*На столе обязательно присутствуют основные блюда:  борщ с пельменями, карп и лапша с маком, изюмом и орехами.*

> Традиция гласит, что чем большое количество мака, тем больше счастья и
>   удачи принесёт наступающий год.

*Традиционно считается, что чем больше мака в блюде (на столе?), тем больше счастья и удачи принесёт наступающий год.*

> После торжественного ужина участники сидят вокруг украшенной ёлки и
>   вместе поют рождественские песни, ожидая Звездного человека, который
>   приносит ребёнком, и даже иногда взрослым, подарки.

*После торжественного ужина участники сидят вокруг украшенной ёлки и
вместе поют рождественские песни, ожидая Звездного человека, который
приносит **детям**, а иногда даже взрослым, подарки.

> Поляки верят, что как проведешь Сочельник, так и будешь жить весь год
>   и потому что они стараются проводить этот день радостно и бес споров.

Поляки верят, что как проведешь Сочельник, так и будешь жить весь год,
и потому они стараются проводить этот день радостно и без споров.

> Праздник Рождества в Польше является символом счастья и благополучия,
>   а также времой распространения этой радости во всех уголках мира.

Не понял того, что после запятой. Поясните, что за распространение "во всех уголках".

*Праздник Рождества в Польше является символом счастья и благополучия, а также временем(?) распространения этой радости во всех уголках мира.*

Comment: А как это -- борщ пельменями? Индийская кухня какая-то? :)

Comment: @Aer **С** пельменями, конечно. Моя вина. А вообще - это вкусно. "Борщ" - жидкая фракция, свекольный отвар по сути. Пельмени - обычнные. Знаю по западноукраинской кухне. Подозревал, что в Польше может быть тоже самое. Вот что такое "лапша с маком" - это загадка. Может, пани Марта просветит.

Comment: Понял. Это клёцки. ))))

Comment: Праздничное время посвящается не только духовному совершенствованию, но и встречу(?!) в семейном кругу.

Comment: @М_Г lf? да, спасибо. Надо всю конструкцию править, иначе не получается.

Comment: Но меня смущает, правильно ли я поступаю, по сути дела выполняю "домашнюю работу".

Comment: Работа домашняя, это видно, но тут вполне понятна ситуация и нашлись желающие помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Рождество в Польше

Рождество ― очень важный момент для всех христиан. Это не только особый духовный опыт, но и время, проведенное в кругу близких людей. Каждая страна имеет свои обычаи, связанные с этим праздником. Польша богата различными интересными традициями, и Рождество для поляков ― это момент повсеместного торжества дружественного, веселого и щедрого рождественского духа,

В Польше время празднования приходится на декабрь. Итак, когда первая звезда, как символ начала праздничных чудес, появляется на тёмном небе, 24 дня декабря, поляки в компании близких садятся к Сочельнику. Но прежде этого они поздравляют друг друга, а иногда даже читают фрагмент Священного Писания, связанный с рождением Иисуса Христа. Многолетняя традиция обязывает, чтобы на праздничном столе было двенадцать блюд. Польская хозяйка, накрывая на стол, обязательно кладет под скатерть немного сена, что знаменует место рождения Христа.

Конечно, нельзя обойтись без таких традиционных кушаний, как борщ с пельменями, карп и лапша с маком, изюмом и орехами. Считается, что чем больше мака, тем больше счастья и удачи принесёт наступающий год. После торжественного ужина участники садятся вокруг украшенной ёлки и вместе поют рождественские песни, ожидая Звездного человека, который приносит подарки детям и взрослым.

Поляки верят, что как проведешь Сочельник, так и будешь жить весь год, и потому они стараются провести этот день в согласии и радости.

Праздник Рождества в Польше является символом счастья и благополучия во всех уголках мира.